# Converting a raw list of words in Wordpad into a standard formatted python list

Tags: python-2.7

I have three raw lists of words in a Wordpad document (just the word followed by enter).  I need to use these lists into my python program.  Is there a convenient way to access these words or automatically apply the correct format for a python 2.7 list?  I don't want to manually type in the ['', '', '']-es on all of them, as it is around 1,000 words in each list.

I'm a beginner at this, really tried to google this, but couldn't phrase the question right, as the results where only on different matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_origin = open ("file_origin.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')

result = []

for word in file_origin:
    result.append(word[:len(word)-1])

file_origin.close()
print(result)
```